# WebLogic Coherence Service Guardian is late, JVM may be running slowly or experienced long GC

Tags: oracle, hibernate, garbage-collection, jvm, weblogic

Good Afternoon,

I'm having the following problem with an application on a weblogic server:

Service guardian is 29854ms late, indicating that this JVM may be running slowly or experienced a long GC

I've been trying solutions by the coherence configuration changing the options 
`
      exit-cluster

```
  <timeout-milliseconds>305000</timeout-milliseconds>
</service-guardian>

<packet-speaker>
  <priority>10</priority>
</packet-speaker>

<packet-publisher>
  <packet-delivery>
    <resend-milliseconds>200</resend-milliseconds>

    <timeout-milliseconds>300000</timeout-milliseconds>

    <heartbeat-milliseconds>1000</heartbeat-milliseconds>
  </packet-delivery>`
```

But this isn't working, I also thought it may be because of hibernate or the connection pool so I made some configuration changes on the config file of hibernate maybe trying c3p0 to control the connections and setting some parameters on the weblogic connection pool of the datasource again with no gain.

What may I be missing to stop experiencing this trouble, after some time the JVM process consumes the 90% of the cpu before showing the GC message, due to this as you may assume the application starts growing slowlier and slowlier.

Edit1: May add the coherence version is 3.7, the configuration is the one that comes by default within the coherence.jar

Edit2: This configuration has been added as well

```
<server-start>
  <arguments>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xss4096k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</arguments>
</server-start>
```

Comment: Already solved it, there was a bad usage of the hibernate (I know there are other ways but it was defined with hibernate) connection so the items were getting loaded over and over again, fixed the connection and problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it, there was a bad usage of the hibernate (I know there are other ways but it was defined with hibernate) connection so the items were getting loaded over and over again, fixed the connection and problem solved